# When using timescaledb should time series data be kept in its own separate Postgres database?

Tags: database-design, timescaledb

Is there any reason to keep time series data in its own database, separate from other tables or is it ok to mix the two in the same database? TimescaleDB docs don't mention any downsides to using hypertables in the same database with other tables without hypertables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Timescale person here,
You don't need to separate regular tables and hypertables, they can definitely live in the same database.  In fact, one of the advantages of TimescaleDB is that you can do JOINs between regular tables and hypertables.  See https://docs.timescale.com/v1.2/introduction/data-model for more info.